# What are the major differences between glide and godep?

Tags: go, dependency-management, package-managers

I have been trying out godep and find it quite useful. However many people have suggested Glide instead, which seems more or less the same to me. Therefore I am wondering the differences between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glide` will download and store it at a directory name `vendor`. Godep simply `go get` dependencies and checkout to the commit you specify in `GoDep` file. I recommend `glide`. It has more flexibility.